# traceroute: findsaddr: write: Invalid argument

Tags: linux, traceroute

I have a FreeBSD machine with traceroute Version 1.4a12+FreeBSD. When I try to run traceroute, I get the following error. However the same command works fine on my Mac.

```
$ traceroute 8.8.8.8
traceroute: findsaddr: write: Invalid argument
$
```

What am I doing wrong?